# Javascript, grading multiply options

Tags: javascript

I have read a lot of topics already but I still do not have a clue what I have to write to make my check() work.

When you choose an option, it will generate multiply questions ( 1 x 1 1 x 2 etc. ) then the user needs to fill in the right answer and when pressed on the submit button it needs to make the good answers green and the bad answers red.

I tried a lot of ways but this time I just can not see it haha. can anyone tell me or bring me in the right direction of what I need to write in my calc()

Thanks for helping :)

```html
<div id="section">
  <h2>De toets</h2>
  <p>Welke toets wil je maken?</p>
  <label for="toetsmenu"></label>
  <select id="toetsmenu" onchange="toets()">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
  </select>
  <div id="toetsding"></div>
  <script>
    function toets() {
      var x = document.getElementById("toetsmenu").value;

      document.getElementById("toetsding").innerHTML = "";
      for (i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
        document.getElementById("toetsding").innerHTML += x + " x " + i +
          " = <input type='text' id='test'>" + "<br>";
      }
      document.getElementById("toetsding").innerHTML += "<input type='submit' value='check' id='sub' onclick='calc()'>"
    }

    function calc() {

    }
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: they all have the same `id="test"` that's bad. IDs should be unique

Comment: Can you show us one of those ways that you tried? What was wrong with it, did you get console errors? incorrect results?

Comment: Or show some desired output. What you are expecting in results.

Comment: @UnknownUser 1x4 should be 4 and so on :)

Comment: Oh sorry, a mistake when i was trying to make it work.

I tried writing the code a few times but I dont know what to or how to adress the right answers.

When the option is 1, the table of 1 shows up, 1 x 1 = 1 x 2 = etc.
Then the user needs to input an answer 

then i want this to happen:

When pressed on the button, the right answers turn green and the wrong answers turn red

as you can see here: [link](http://blackkiwi.nl/boterbloem/images/this.png)

Comment: @DennisVanZanten did my answer work for you? If not please comment it

Comment: It worked! great! thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating the `<input>` elements you need to give them each a unique ID: `id='test" + i + "`

In the `calc()` function you can then simply access them by their ID in the loop and check the result

```js
function toets() {
  var x = document.getElementById("toetsmenu").value;

  document.getElementById("toetsding").innerHTML = "";
  for (i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    document.getElementById("toetsding").innerHTML += x + " x " + i +
      " = <input type='text' id='test" + i + "'>" + "<br>";
  }
  document.getElementById("toetsding").innerHTML += "<input type='submit' value='check' id='sub' onclick='calc()'>"
}

function calc() {
  var x = document.getElementById("toetsmenu").value

  for (i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    var input = document.getElementById("test" + i)
    var result = input.value
    console.log(input.value)
    if (result == x * i) {
      input.className = "correct"
    } else {
      input.className = "wrong"
    }
  }

}

toets()
```

```css
.wrong {
  background-color: red;
}
.correct {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="section">
  <h2>De toets</h2>
  <p>Welke toets wil je maken?</p>
  <label for="toetsmenu"></label>
  <select id="toetsmenu" onchange="toets()">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
  </select>
  <div id="toetsding"></div>
</div>
```